# PHP - Do I need to validate this simple form for security?

Tags: php, forms, validation, security, xss

I'm building a small website where I'll be the only user (let say my credentials are "myuser" with the password "mypassword"). In the login page I have this simple form:

```
<form method="post">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="usr"></p>
<p>Password: <input type="text" name="passwd"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

Is it safe to just validate the form like this?

```
// After checking if the request is POST...
if($_POST["usr"]=="myuser"&&$_POST["passwd"]=="mypassword") {
     // Set the cookie and go to admin page...
} else {
     // Show login error...
}
```

Or do I need to apply some security measure to the two $_POST variables (e.g. by filtering them with htmlspecialchars or something like that)? As you can see, the credentials are not saved in a database, and also these variables are never called anywhere else in the code, so I don't see any danger even if a malicious user attempts to hack the form with SQL Injection or XSS.

So, did I miss something? Is there any potential danger in leaving the code like that?

Comment: There will surely be some war mongers saying  this is insane, but it is fine.

Comment: You should however take care to use ssl encryption (https).

Comment: *where I'll be the only user* by that u mean the website won't be online?

Comment: Someone could still brute-force the login details. And there is no CSRF protection.

Comment: @ arkascha: yes, I'll use HTTPS.

Comment: @ Masivuye Cokile: I'll be the only user with an account. Normal site visitors will just browse the site and won't be able to create an account.

Comment: @ Niraj Shah: I'm going to use reCAPTCHA to prevent brute force attacks. I'll investigate about CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine, you can add a hashe function & something to prevent a brute force attack to secure a little more. :)
(Sorry can't comment yet)

Comment: About brute force, I'll add reCAPTCHA before the site goes live.

Answer (score -2):

With php we can use mysql_real_scape_string(), this function have a parameter that modify a string deleting the special chars. This function returns a secure string, now we can execute this string into a SQL query.

Comment: Read the question

Comment: There is no database connected to this form, so even if an user puts a SQL query in the form, nothing would happen.